# MYSQL Fetching rows into page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am fetching data from mysql to a page, i am not sure if the way im doing it is appropiate. I am having trouble with fetching values into sections of the page.

```
<?php
    // Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die (mysql_error ());

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());

    // SQL query
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM news";

    // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

    // Loop the recordset $rs
    // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

       // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
      echo $row['editor_name'] . " " . $row['news_desc'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();
    ?>

</div>  <!-- content #end -->
```

the database;
[image: db]

the above yields;

[image: news]

I want to do the following;
BY: Fadi

```
echo 'BY' $row['editor_name'] . " " . $row['news_desc'];
      echo "<br />";
```

but it isn't working :( any tips

Comment: search for "php mysql charset utf-8"

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: `echo 'BY' $row['editor_name'] . " " . $row['news_desc']; echo "<br />";` should be `echo 'BY' . $row['editor_name'] . " " . $row['news_desc']; echo "<br />";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a concat operator after 'BY'. Should be

```
echo 'BY' . $row['editor_name'] . " " . $row['news_desc'];
echo "<br />";
```

OR tidier:

```
echo "BY {$row['editor_name']} {$row['news_desc']}<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return associative array you can try using this line:

```
...

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one dot after `'BY'`

```
echo 'BY' . $row['editor_name'] . ' ' . $row['news_desc'] . '<br />';
```